# Roll back tsddkiller quarantine driver files

Tags: windows-xp

After using kaspersky TDSSkiller on a old dell 5100 that iwas convinced was infected i quarantined 7 items ,all drivers.Now D drive,is not usable,usb ports,even internet connections gone.Have installed dell drivers,microsoft,tried every trick in the book inc s restore.No luck.After researching this subject i found i am one of many many people.Over a year ago KKPY said they would introduce rollback option.Anybody help would be grateful .ty.

Comment: hate to suggest the obvious but would reinstalling be an option?

Comment: like i said every trick in the book,even dell test as soon as it reached usb stage froze solid.nothing works.

Comment: If its still broken after reinstalling, its no longer a software issue

Comment: look up kaspersky forum ,no answers only next version will have rollback function,i am lucky it is a old machine that i was gonna use for backup.